# What value is stored in linux xtime variable?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, time, interrupt

Whenever I print the value of `/proc/interrupts` the value of `rtc0` in `IRQ8` which is for RTC shows only 1 interrupt on CPU0. I have read that when booting the value of the xtime variable is stored from the Real time Clock and whether this interrupt is 1 because of this?

And also what would be the value of the xtime variable? Is it the number of seconds passed after epoch?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at that interrupt under `/proc/irq/8` it seems to confirm some of what you're saying:

```
$ ls /proc/irq/8/
affinity_hint  node  rtc0/  smp_affinity  spurious
```

Contents of those files:

```
/proc/irq/8/affinity_hint: 
0

/proc/irq/8/node: 
0

/proc/irq/8/smp_affinity: 
f

/proc/irq/8/spurious: 
count 1
unhandled 0
last_unhandled 0 ms
```

#### References

- [4.3. Interrupts and IRQ Tuning - RHEL Portal](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/s-cpu-irq.html)
- [Real Time Clock (RTC) Drivers for Linux](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/rtc.txt)